# Evenet Listener is not executing the functions

Tags: javascript, html, css

Althoug in inline onmauseover="verdadero()" works perfectly

Reviewing I realized that although the box acquires the event listener, simply when I hover over the element the function is not executed, nor is the console.log even written

Note: The Html is simplified for practical purposes

```
let onCuadro = false;

const cuadro = document.getElementsByClassName("overscroll__box");

for (let i = 0; i < cuadro.length; i++) {
  cuadro[i].addEventListener("onmouseover", verdadero,true);
}

for (let i = 0; i < cuadro.length; i++) {
  cuadro[i].addEventListener("onmouseleave", falso,true);
}

function verdadero() {
  console.log("onCuadro = true");
  onCuadro = true;
}

function falso() {
  console.log("onCuadro = false");
  onCuadro = false;
}
```

html :

```
 <div class="overscroll__box"></div>
 <div class="overscroll__box"></div>
 <script src="./index.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

*Event names* should not be prefixed with `on`. Use `on` when using:

- An inline handler, eg `<button onclick=`, or
- When invoking the IDL getter or setter, eg `button.onclick = function() {

But when using `addEventListener`, only use the event name, without `on`. The event name here would be `mouseover` or `mouseleave`.

```
for (let i = 0; i < cuadro.length; i++) {
  cuadro[i].addEventListener("mouseover", verdadero,true);
  cuadro[i].addEventListener("mouseleave", falso,true);
}
```

Or, more concisely

```
for (const box of document.getElementsByClassName("overscroll__box")) {
  box.addEventListener("mouseover", verdadero, true);
  box.addEventListener("mouseleave", falso, true);
}
```

(You also may well not need to pass a third parameter to `addEventListener` unless the event delegation really is doing something useful for you)